# How to getGravity() in custom view?

Tags: android, custom-view

Can't get gravity attribute (`android:gravity`) from my CustomView.

XML

```
<MyCustomView
 ...
 android:gravity="right"
 />
```

My Custom View;

```
class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout{
 ...
 @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    getGravity(); //Throws method not found exception
    ((LayoutParams)getLayoutParams()).gravity; //This returns the value of android:layout_gravity
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
 ...
}
```

`getGravity();` throws method not found exception;

`((LayoutParams)getLayoutParams()).gravity;` returns the value of android:layout_gravity

Is there anyway I can get the gravity attribute from the view?

Comment: First you need to understand that the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` are not the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/94/layouts/398/gravity-and-layout-gravity#t=201608101551183172231

Comment: I know bro. I think you are not clear with the question. I want to get the  value of gravity attribute that I put in XML from my java code. Not layout_gravity. I can get the layout_gravity but not gravity.

Comment: @BartekLipinski I dont think he is confused about the two, just that he is able to get one, but not the other, and questions why he can't `getGravity()`

Comment: I don't know if this works but It seems that you might try Reflection like this on lower API, but use getGravity from android 24. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/38605915/4183017

Comment: @Doomsknight oh yea, sorry... Just peeked through the question (didn't read it thoroughly), and thought this distinction was relevant ;)

Comment: ok..sry... I deleted my answer..that 'getGravity' thing is available for >24, you can implement it following the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558289/get-linearlayout-gravity

Answer (score 9):

The `getGravity()` method of `LinearLayout` was only made public starting with API 24. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38605915/3681880) suggests a way to get it in earlier versions by using reflection.

For just a normal custom view, you can access the gravity attribute like this:

Declare the `android:gravity` attribute in your [custom attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). [Don't set the format.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27050778/3681880)

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="android:gravity" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Set the gravity in your project layout xml.

```
<com.example.myproject.CustomView
    ...
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Get the gravity attribute in the constructor.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private int mGravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, 0, 0);

        try {
            mGravity = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomView_android_gravity, Gravity.TOP);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public int getGravity() {
        return mGravity;
    }

    public void setGravity(int gravity) {
        if (mGravity != gravity) {
            mGravity = gravity;
            invalidate();    
        }
    }
}
```

Or instead of using the `android:gravity` attribute, you could define your own custom `gravity` attribute that uses the same flag values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676977/3681880).

Comment: Great answer, but how do you then use mGravity to actually set the gravity of the view or elements in the view?

Comment: @molundb, Sorry, I can't remember anymore. I've switched to Flutter for all my Android development.