# How to check gravity flags in a custom Android View?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, flags, android-gravity

**The problem**

I have a custom Android view in which I want get the user set gravity in order to layout the content in `onDraw`. Here is a simplified version that I am using in `onDraw`:

```
// check gravity
if ((mGravity & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) == Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) {
    // draw the content centered vertically
} else if ((mGravity & Gravity.BOTTOM) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
    // draw the content at the bottom
}
```

where `mGravity` is obtained from the xml attributes ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173923/3681880)).

If I set the gravity to `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` it works fine. But I was surprised to find that if I set it to `Gravity.BOTTOM`, the `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` check is still true!

**Why is this happening?**

I had to look at the binary values to see why:

- Binary: `0001 0000`,   [`Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER_VERTICAL): Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)
- Binary: `0101 0000`,   [`Gravity.BOTTOM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#BOTTOM): Constant Value: 80 (0x00000050)

Thus, when I do

```
mGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
(mGravity & Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) == Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
//  (0101 & 0001) == 0001
```

I get a false positive.

**What do I do?**

So how am I supposed to check the gravity flags?

I could do something like `if (mGravity == Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)`, but then I would only get an exact match. If the user set gravity to something like `center_vertical|right` then it would fail.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can examine how [`FrameLayout`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/FrameLayout.java) lays its children. Particularly, this code:

```
final int layoutDirection = getLayoutDirection();
final int absoluteGravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(gravity, layoutDirection);
final int verticalGravity = gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;

switch (absoluteGravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) {
    case Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL:
        ...
    case Gravity.RIGHT:
        ...
    case Gravity.LEFT:
        ...
}

switch (verticalGravity) {
    case Gravity.TOP:
        ...
    case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
        ...
    case Gravity.BOTTOM:
        ...
}
```

There're masks in `Gravity` class: `VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK`, `HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK` which will help you to find out what gravities have been applied.

Comment: I finished testing this and I can confirm it works. I was missing the `VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK`.

Answer (score 12):

This is a supplemental answer to @azizbekian's very helpful solution. I'm adding this to help myself more fully understand how gravity works behind the scenes.

### Horizontal axis gravity

`LEFT` and `RIGHT` are known as absolute gravity. That is, if a user specifies a relative gravity of `START` or `END`, then it is [converted internally](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/Gravity.java#Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity%28int%2Cint%29) to an absolute gravity of `RIGHT` or `LEFT` depending on the situation.

```
0000 0001  CENTER_HORIZONTAL
0000 0011  LEFT
0000 0101  RIGHT
---------  
0000 0111  HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK
```

A note about `START` and `END`

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011  START
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011  LEFT
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101  END
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101  RIGHT
-----------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111  HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK
```

As you can see here, `START` and `LEFT` only differ by a single bit. It is the same for `END` and `RIGHT`. Thus, if you use the `HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK` directly on `START` and `END`, they will default to `LEFT` and `RIGHT` respectively. However, this should be used with caution. Right-to-left language locales should be taken into consideration.

### Vertical axis gravity

The y axis gravity is shifted over 4 bits from the x axis (horizontal) gravity.

```
0001 0000  CENTER_VERTICAL
0011 0000  TOP
0101 0000  BOTTOM
---------
0111 0000  VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK
```

### Both axes

Note that `CENTER` is a combination of `CENTER_VERTICAL` and `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`. Thus, you can also use one of the gravity masks to convert it.

```
0000 0001  CENTER_HORIZONTAL
0001 0000  CENTER_VERTICAL
0001 0001  CENTER
---------
0000 0111  HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK
0111 0000  VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK
```

### Bit math

Use the bit OR operator (`|`) to combine horizontal and vertical gravity.

Example:

```
int myGravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;

0000 0101  RIGHT
0101 0000  BOTTOM
---------
0101 0101  myGravity
```

Use the bit AND operator (`&`) with one of the gravity masks to isolate the horizontal or vertical gravity.

Example

```
int verticalGravity = myGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
if (verticalGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) ...

0101 0101  myGravity
0111 0000  VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK
---------
0101 0000  verticalGravity
0101 0000  BOTTOM
```

Comment: `I'm adding this to help myself `, maan, this is something not only for you certainly. Nice, detailed!